# Is it possible to change the storage allocation for specific cells in a database?

Tags: sql, database, storage

I am aware that when writing a program, upon declaration of a string, int etc., a uniform amount of memory is allocated depending the value's type. I am also aware of the existence of the type varchar in many SQL dialects - a dynamic datatype that allows the user to determine the amount of storage allocated for a column. However, I am curious of whether or not there is a way to change the amount of storage allocated for specific cells no matter what their column's datatype is (INTEGER, REAL, TEXT, BLOB, etc.) in any modern database environment. For example, rather than reserving a specific amount of storage space for each cell created in a column, I would like it so each value is only taking up the true amount of space that it requires- regardless of its true type's predetermined allocation.

If it seems that my understanding of this topic is misconstrued or if you have any insight on the topic, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TEXT and BLOB types are usually already stored as dynamic storage, much akin to a file.

VARCHAR and VARBINARY are usually variable width, but it depends on the DBMS.

Variable width columns result in rows that are no longer the same length. This adds a complication because now the DBMS cannot use simple math to know where any row starts - if every row were `X` bytes, then the `Nth` row starts at byte `X*N`. That math becomes impossible with variable length rows.

DBMS's can handle this by way of one of two means:

- Row-scanning - to find the Nth row, start with the 1st row, find out how long it is, jump to the end to find the next row, find out how long it is .. and so on.
- Indexing: maintain a table that stores the length of every row.

Indexing requires more memory (disk and ram) to keep, but is fast. Row scanning requires no extra memory, but is intensely slow for all but the smallest workloads.

Unless you're dealing with large variable-length values, it is usually not worth it to use variable-length types.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to vary by database vendor, so I can tell you from an Oracle perspective. 
Oracle's VARCHAR2 datatype is a variable length string. You have to specify a maximum size up to 32k, but only the actual data is stored. 
You can change datatypes too, within certain restrictions. For example, you can change NUMBER to VARCHAR2(). 
Oracle CHAR datatype however is fixed length and as such is subject to different character comparison semantics compared to VARCHAR2().

I hope that helps.